# Empty error when running Table to Excel tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, excel

The Table to Excel tool in the Conversion toolbox does not work for some reason. When I open it, it shows a red cross in the top left corner. When I try to run it an error pops up that says nothing. I've tried different input tables, different output locations and tried to do it it in python, which gives the "serious application error" and quits ArcMap. The result does not even show up in the geoprocessing window.

I have ArcMap 10.5.1.

[image: Tool when I open it.]

[image: Tool when I run it.]

Comment: Have you seen this thread, mainly suggestions [Table to Excel Tool](https://community.esri.com/thread/168633)?

Comment: @Taras Yeah, I have tried to run it in an new, empty map.

Comment: Please expand on "breaks the whole program" -- do you mean you get a Serious Application Error dialog? These should be reported to Esri Tech Support.

Comment: @Vince Thats correct.

Comment: Then please [Edit] the question to contain this. Did you report the error to Esri?

Comment: @Vince I did not report it yet as I have not had the time to reproduce it.

Comment: If you hover over the red x, is there any error message?

Comment: @mkennedy No, unfortunately. I have discovered that the problem is with the python installation on the PC. That's why the tools not working and python gives the Serious application error.